# Other way to trigger the take a photo confirmation button?

Tags: android, photo

So during development I have dropped my only android device on the ground :(. A nexus 7 (1st gen) and now 1/5 of the screen doesn't work anymore. Unfortunatly, for me my little testing app makes use of the camera and I can't push the "confirm" button after taking a picture (I take a photo with the volume buttons).

1/ any way to alter my code so that a "confirm" check is not needed and a taken photo is automaticlly the photo to use?

2/ other way to "confirm" a taken picture?

3/ move the camera controls with the orientation to other sides

Code I use to capture a picture

```
public class TestCamera extends Activity {
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera_layout);

        this.imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                        android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
//         if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }
}
```

Any tips, smart suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

Try using INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA instead of ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA

I had the same problem but I ended up implementing my own camera app using android.hardware.Camera.

Comment: i am trying your suggestion and the picture are taken but it doesn't return and show the image in the imageview. My app just shows the camera ui. I don't know if i was clear, but because of dropping my android device i am not able to click the confirm button. With INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA  there's no confirm button, but onActivityResult is not triggered.

Comment: With INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA it will save the picture automatically so I guess you won't get any result you can use and set your imageView.

Depends on how you will use you app but you can simulate a touch event but using ADB. To press the button to confirm the photo.

"adb shell input swipe     100 1000 100 10"

It will simulate a touch event from coordinates x1,y1 to x2, y2.